# java hibernate criteria error

Tags: java, hibernate, criteria

Here the database schema:

```
Table A:                public class A {
id integer,                B objectB;
comment varchar(30),       String comment;         
id_B integer            }

Table B:                public class B {
id integer,                C objectC;
comment varchar(20),       String comment;
network integer         }

Table C:                public class C {
id                         Integer id;
name varchar(30)           String name;
                         }
```

Now I need to create a Criteria that checks for the proper 'id' in Table C and the 'comment' in Table B. I tried to do:

```
Criteria criteria = getSession().createCriteria(A.class);
criteria.createCriteria("objectB")
        .createCriteria("objectC").add(Restrictions.idEq(networkID));

//gives org.hibernate.QueryException: duplicate association path: objectB error
if (comment != null && comment.length() > 0) {
    criteria.createCriteria("objectB")
            .add(Restrictions.like("comment", "%" + comment + "%"));
}

//second approach gives me no error but does not work, means I receive the wrong results
if (comment != null && comment.length > 0) {
    criteria.add(Restrictions.like("comment", "%" + comment + "%"));
}
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I don't think it likes that the code creates to `Criteria` objects for `objectB`.  Also there is a syntax error within the code.

**Revised**

```
Criteria criteria = getSession().createCriteria(A.class);
Criteria criteriaB = criteria.createCriteria("objectB");
Criteria criteriaC = criteriaB.createCriteria("objectC");
criteriaB.add(Restrictions.like("comment", "%" + comment + "%"));
criteriaC.add(Restrictions.idEq(networkID));
```

**Syntax Issue**

```
Criteria criteria = getSession().createCriteria(A.class);
criteria.createCriteria("objectB")
        .createCriteria("objectC").add(Restrictions.idEq(networkID));

//Syntax error occurs here, missing add
criteria.createCriteria("objectB")
        .(Restrictions.like("comment", "%" + comment + "%"));

//Fix
criteria.createCriteria("objectB").add(Restrictions.like("comment", "%" + comment + "%"));
```

Answer (score 0):

Try this. You do not need to call   createCriteria("objectB") two times

```
  Criteria criteria = getSession().createCriteria(A.class);
  criteria.createCriteria("objectB").createCriteria("objectC").add(Restrictions.idEq(networkID)).add(Restrictions.like("comment", "%" + comment + "%"));

if (comment != null && comment.length > 0) {
    criteria.createAlias("objectB", "b")
    criteria.add(Restrictions.like("b.comment", "%" + comment + "%"));
}
```

Comment: sorry I forgot to mention that the second criteria 'comment' is added in an if-clause only if the comment is not null, I tried your solution and updated my code but it didn't work

Comment: do you try it with alias?http://docs.jboss.org/hibernate/orm/3.3/reference/en/html/querycriteria.html#querycriteria-associations